# iphone 4 compass and map

Tags: iphone, google-maps, compass-geolocation, cllocation

how to use compass based on direction on google maps using iphone 4 ,as MAPS app doing

any tutorial to refer??

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `locationManager:didUpdateHeading:`, apply a cooresponding rotation transform to your map view:

```
double headingInRadians = newHeading.trueHeading * M_PI / 180.0;
mapView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(headingInRadians);
```

The map view's frame should be a little bigger than the visible area so that no blank corners show up when it's rotated.

Comment: i did exactly but my map is not moving :(

Comment: hey how to get tht blue dots for current location?? and that too blinking one ???